# How to make slider like this?

Tags: slider

How to make a slider like this link that the one in the site http://demo.rehabdigital.com/ethical-2/. I shall be very thankful to my brother who will answer me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slidder is realized with [Flexslider v 2.0](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but please also tell me how to do it's coding.

Comment: Include jQuery and flexslider javascript library.. There are examples on theire website how to do..